# Заменить регулярным выражением пробелы при условии

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Доброй день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как должно выглядеть регулярное выражение, которое будет заменять пробелы (**`&nbsp;`**) там, где их более трех штук на три пробела! Я пишу так, но что-то работает совсем криво:

```
$text = preg_replace('/&nbsp;/xsi', '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $text);
```

Спасибо!

Чуть изменил шаблон регулярного выражения.. Почему-то не работает шаблон такого вида:

```
/&nbsp;{3,}/xsi
```

Comment: Потому что этот шаблон для чего-то вроде этого `&nbsp;;;;;;`

Answer (score 2):

Сделал следующим образом:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(&nbsp;\s){3,}/xsi', '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $text);
```

Comment: [\s][1] - это не только пробел.


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = preg_replace('/(&nbsp;){3,}/i', '\\1\\1\\1', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в цикле менять четыре пробела на три, до тех пор, пока не останется по три.